# How can I use SkPy to send a specific message when receving a specific message

Tags: python, message, skype, skype4py

Essentially I'm trying to create a very simple script that will send predesignated messages when a defined message is received. I'm new to Python.

What I have is basically this:

```
from skpy import Skype
sk = Skype("myskypeID", "pwd") # connect to Skype
content="the message i wanna send"
ch = sk.contacts["SkypeID_in_contacts"].chat 
ch.sendMsg(content)
```

This will send a single message once to a designated account. How would I go about making it so that I can send specific messages to said account based on what messages I get from it?

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://skpy.t.allofti.me ?

Comment: @AMC No, although I read some documentation. Hopefully I'll be able to figure this out from here. Thanks.

Comment: It seems quite nice actually.